# How can I edit the CSS on an Access Custom Web App hosted on Sharepoint Online?

Tags: ms-access, azure, sharepoint, ms-access-2013, ms-access-web-app

I want to hide the filter-box div on a List View in an Access 2013 Custom Web App, but do not know how I can get to the css files on the server.

I can't seem to find them on Sharepoint Designer, and am wondering if they are within Azure?  Could I access my Azure server hosted by Microsoft with a certain tool?  Visual Studio, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your SharePoint Online instance is through Office365. Regardless, best practice is to override the CSS styles that SharePoint has, rather than changing them. The easiest way to do this is through the browser by just adding a Content Editor Webpart(CEWP) to the same page and then add your overriding css styles to that webpart. Then make the CEWP hidden so it just runs behind the scenes.

Heres a detailed link for instructions:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/40e97e/content-editor-web-part-and-css-tricks/

Comment: Thank you.  One thing I can't seem to figure out in the article you linked to is the starting point.  What tool am I supposed to use to edit the Content Editor Web Part?  I have been trying to find it in Sharepoint Designer.  You say "through the browser", but I don't see how to take the first step using the browser.

Comment: @MichaelBlaustein Here is a better walkthrough adding a CEWP for SP 2013, with good pictures http://blog.cloudshare.com/2012/10/29/how-to-insert-custom-javascript-code-in-sharepoint-2013-pages-part-i/

Comment: Thanks again.  That does seem like it would be a good solution if indeed I could get at the web page which the Access 2013 Custom Web App creates.  It seems that the web app is not, in fact hosted on Sharepoint, but rather on an Azure Web Site somewhere.  Can you confirm or deny this?  Thanks again.

Comment: My method will not work if the site is not built on the SharePoint platform. SharePoint Designer will not work for editing the site either. If the site is hosted in Azure, you could possible login to the Azure portal assuming you have the credentials to do so, and find the instance it is hosted on. If its on a VM then you could look for the code base on that machine by RDPing into it. If its deployed as an Azure Website, then its most likely hooked up to some type of source control which you could edit. Regardless you will need to login to manage.windowsazure.com to find all of this out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this applies to SP online, but on premises  you can turn on publishing for the site and use an alternate CSS to apply styles to you Access Web APP.  I've got a blog on it here:
[Apply styles to access web application](http://coyleonsharepoint.wordpress.com/2014/08/27/apply-styles-to-access-web-application/)

Comment: Please post relevant part here not just link.